# firewalld is it required to open ports for localhost apps using that port on same server?

Tags: centos, localhost, firewalld

Is it required to open ports for localhost apps using that port on same server? I mean not extra connections are made from external servers..

for example i have installed `memcached` service which requires a port on its settings(port 11211 for example) for the service delivery. Do I need any trust rule for that port to add in my firewalld to get it working for other local services and applications like php?

Comment: I don't believe you should have to add firewall rules to allow traffic to/from the same host, but it likely depends on the application. Have you tried accessing `memcached` from the loopback interface (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: @ResetACK No I did not performed any tests, I just want to make sure that service is not being blocked by firewall logically. I believe I do not need to open any ports in firewall because of my local services, but I'm not sure about this and not found any resource describing such topic to make me sure about such thing. Maybe I should asked this kind of question on stackoverflow because this seems to be more related to logical procedures than administrating servers.